# Sync an object with respected xml document

Tags: c#, xml, object

I am working on a WPF project were i need to store all the objects in separate xml documents in the local file system. However now i am updating my xml documents each time whenever i change my objects. Is there is a way to sync those objects with there corresponding xml documents in c#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One way sync: save new document every time object changes. Two way sync: one way sync + `FileSystemWatcher` to update object when file changes.

Comment: I think one way sync is enough for me. So finally i need to update the document whenever i change my object?

Comment: Yes, you do. At least I cannot see any other option.

Comment: Okay let it be. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can write an interface and implement it on every data object in your code. Have a look at the code below. You will have to still call the sync method manually but I think it is more clean code.

```
public interface IDataChangeHandler
{
    void OnDataChanged(object data, string tag);
}

public class DataObject : IDataChangeHandler
{
    private string _property1;
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _property1; }
        set
        {
            _property1 = value;
            OnDataChanged(_property1, "property1");
        }
    }

    private int _property2;
    public int Property2
    {
        get { return _property2; }
        set
        {
            _property2 = value;
            OnDataChanged(_property2, "property2");
        }
    }


    public void OnDataChanged(object data, string tag)
    {
        /*write the changes in xml*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Saving the XML every time single property value changes doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: That is true. But I think there should be some view models. and implementing the interface on original model objects only (not view models) can save some resource.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged` in the classes of those objects which you want to save in xml. See the following example:

```
public class Class1ToSave : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private int _property1;

    public int Property1
    {
        get
        {
            return _property1;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_property1 != value)
            {
                _property1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Property1");
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
    }
}
```

After that, you may subscribe to PropertyChanged event of `Class1ToSave` from client code where you have written the code for saving data to xml.

Its up to you whether you save data to xml after each property change or just log the changes in an appropriate list. The list may be bulk-saved at a later appropriate time for optimization issue.

In this way, whenever the value of a property changes, the listener picks the updated property value and saves it to the xml.